# Overclock NVIDIA GPU at lower voltages

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, gpu

I would like to overclock my NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti Max-Q GPU. Reason: improved performance. Inspired from:

- [How I stopped my XPS 15 7590 GPU from throttling](https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/cdq5wr/how_i_stopped_my_xps_15_7590_gpu_from_throttling/)

I would prefer to directly undervolt the GPU, but as far as I know that is not possible since NVIDIA locked the voltage controls.

---

The first step towards overclocking is to enable `Coolbits`, which after some [hassle](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/hfj11d/nvidiaxconfig_breaks_boot/) I've learned how to do.

Now, for the overclocking process I can simply run `nvidia-settings` and in the `PowerMizer` section I can set my Graphics Clock Offset / Memory Transfer Rate Offset, or I can use [GreenWithEnvy](https://gitlab.com/leinardi/gwe/). I prefer to use GWE.

Before I do that, I would like to find answers to a few questions. I have asked them on [GWE's gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/leinardi/gwe/-/issues/122#note_368906873) and will reproduce them here. Please correct me if what I wrote doesn't make sense.

---

My understanding is that the GPU works according to some default frequency/voltage curve.
For example:

[image]

When the GPU performs a minor task it can run at a lower frequency with less voltages, when it has to do something more computationally intensive, it will run at higher frequency requiring more voltages.

On Windows, with MSI Afterburner, one can overclock ([video](https://youtu.be/zUkPAVcb9Xc?t=516)) at lower voltages simply by dragging the curve up:

[image]

This way we manage to effectively undervolt, as the GPU would be running at its highest frequency with lower voltage.

**Questions**:

1. Can this be done on Linux, i.e. overclock at different voltages differently?
2. What does the GPU offset actually do? Does it move the entire curve by that offset?
   Assume there is a stock max frequency (i.e. the hardcoded max frequency at which the GPU can run) level of 1900 Mhz and the min frequency on the curve is 1350 Mh (just as in the first picture). If I successfully set an overclock offset of 550 Mhz, am I right to think that my GPU will always operate at 1900 Mhz consuming 700 mV?
3. What is a good/safe Mem offset level? Is the GPU offset stress-testing also appropriate for Mem clock offset?

Comment: You'd better ask here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148